# Google Maps Reverse Coding API suddenly starts failing

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In my react native app I am using Google Reverse geoCoding API to get location names from lat-lng. It was working fine for months, and it suddenly starts failing now.

The query that i was using :

```
fetch("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" +
            this.state.region.latitude + "," +
            this.state.region.longitude +
            "&key=" + GOOGLE_API_KEY
    )
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(responseJson => { ... })
```

I realized that i was using it wrong all these months as it should be `.../json/latlng` instead of `.../json/address`. So I corrected it now :

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=....`

as mentioned in the [Offical Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/overview#reverse-example)

Still its not giving any results, despite saying status : 200

Below is the response I am getting from this `fetch` call, it doesnt give any significant info of what could be wrong.

```
{
    "type": "default",
    "status": 200,
    "ok": true,
    "headers": {
        "map": {
            "content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
            "server-timing": "gfet4t7; dur=17",
            "pragma": "no-cache",
            "alt-svc": "h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-27=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"",
            "cache-control": "no-cache, must-revalidate",
            "server": "mafe",
            "expires": "Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT",
            "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
            "x-xss-protection": "0",
            "content-encoding": "gzip",
            "date": "Sun, 20 Sep 2020 15:01:41 GMT",
            "content-length": "200",
            "vary": "Accept-Language",
            "x-frame-options": "SAMEORIGIN"
        }
    },
    "url": "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=12.991999943565116,77.72999983280897&key=XXXXXXXXXX",  // Instead of XXX there was correct key
    "bodyUsed": false,
    "_bodyInit": {
        "_data": {
            "size": 256,
            "offset": 0,
            "blobId": "2728F9A1-2861-4EDB-A9B7-1500F3F5205C",
            "type": "application/json",
            "name": "json",
            "__collector": {}
        }
    },
    "_bodyBlob": {
        "_data": {
            "size": 256,
            "offset": 0,
            "blobId": "2728F9A1-2861-4EDB-A9B7-1500F3F5205C",
            "type": "application/json",
            "name": "json",
            "__collector": {}
        }
    }
}
```

I tried giving multiple different lat lng pairs (which were working earlier), but it doesnt work anymore.

I have a valid Google Maps Billing Account with a few hundred USD already in the credit. So it's not the billing issue as well.

---

**UPDATE**

When I put this query in browser (as suggested by @geocodezip in comment) it gives a billing related error response :

```
{
   "error_message" : "You must enable Billing on the Google Cloud Project at https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/billing/enable Learn more at https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started",
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

Although the billing is already enabled. I am now talking to the Google Cloud Support, to get it resolved.

Comment: The query you posted works for me in a browser when I add my key.  Does the URL work for you in a browser with your key?

Comment: @geocodezip, thanks for the suggestion. It looks like billing issue. (i ve updated the question), please put your comment as answer (that it could be billing issue), I ll mark it resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I talked to the Google Support and they told me that it **could be** because the registered billing account (for Google Cloud Platform) was in INR and its no longer compatible with Google Maps Platform Due to India migration.

https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-india-faq#bill-why

And I have to change my (Google Cloud) project billing account from INR to a USD billing account. Despite my Google Maps billing account already in USD.

(Yes they are different. Google Maps billing acc & Google Cloud Billing acc)

**Without any warning email, Google Maps suspended the maps API service abruptly !!**

People using maps apis in their production app, please take care.